# I want to insert two different sizes of images using single File upload Using ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to insert two different sizes of images using single file upload.

I had inserted one image which has size 101 but I need to insert another 51 size small image of the same user.

```
id  BigImage    SmallImage
 1  mazhar.jpg  NULL
 2  mazhar.jpg  NULL
 3  12_n.jpg    NULL
```

I need result like below:

```
 id BigImage    SmallImage
 1  mazhar.jpg  smallmazhar.jpg
 2  mazhar.jpg  smallmazhar.jpg
 3  12_n.jpg    small12_n.jpg
```

C# code is given below:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     //http://forums.asp.net/t/1079883.aspx?PageIndex=1
    string Status = string.Empty;
    int id = 0;

    const int bmpW = 101;
    //New image target width

    const int bmpH = 101;
    //New Image target height

    bo.Para1 = FileUpload1.FileName.ToString();// Passing parameter

    if ((FileUpload1.HasFile))
    {
        //Clear the error label text
        lblError.Text = "";

        //Check to make sure the file to upload has a picture file format extention and set the target width and height

        if ((CheckFileType(FileUpload1.FileName)))
        {
            Int32 newWidth = bmpW;
            Int32 newHeight = bmpH;

            //Use the uploaded filename for saving without the '.' extension

            String upName = FileUpload1.FileName.Substring(0, FileUpload1.FileName.IndexOf("."));

            //Set the save path of the resized image, you will need this directory already created in your web site

       //   string filePath = "~/Upload/" + upName + ".jpg";

            bl.Insert_PhotoInfo(bo, out Status, out id);

            string filePath = Convert.ToString(id) + bo.Para1;

           FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Request.ServerVariables["APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH"] + "Upload/" + filePath);

            //Create a new Bitmap using the uploaded picture as a Stream

            //Set the new bitmap resolution to 72 pixels per inch

            Bitmap upBmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromStream(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream);

            Bitmap newBmp = new Bitmap(newWidth, newHeight, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

            newBmp.SetResolution(72, 72);

            //Get the uploaded image width and height

            Double upWidth = upBmp.Width;

            Double upHeight = upBmp.Height;

            int newX = 0;
            //Set the new top left drawing position on the image canvas

            int newY = 0;

            Double reDuce;

            //Keep the aspect ratio of image the same if not 4:3 and work out the newX and newY positions

            //to ensure the image is always in the centre of the canvas vertically and horizontally

            if (upWidth > upHeight)
            {
                //Landscape picture
                reDuce = newWidth / upWidth;

                //calculate the width percentage reduction as decimal
                newHeight = ((Int32)(upHeight * reDuce));

                //reduce the uploaded image height by the reduce amount
                newY = ((Int32)((bmpH - newHeight) / 2));

                //Position the image centrally down the canvas
                newX = 0;
                //Picture will be full width
            }
            else if (upWidth < upHeight)
            {
                //Portrait picture
                reDuce = newHeight / upHeight;

                //calculate the height percentage reduction as decimal
                newWidth = ((Int32)(upWidth * reDuce));

                //reduce the uploaded image height by the reduce amount
                newX = ((Int32)((bmpW - newWidth) / 2));

                //Position the image centrally across the canvas
                newY = 0;
                //Picture will be full hieght
            }
            else if (upWidth == upHeight)
            {
                //square picture
                reDuce = newHeight / upHeight;

                //calculate the height percentage reduction as decimal
                newWidth = ((Int32)(upWidth * reDuce));

                //reduce the uploaded image height by the reduce amount
                newX = ((Int32)((bmpW - newWidth) / 2));
                //Position the image centrally across the canvas


                newY = ((Int32)((bmpH - newHeight) / 2));
                //Position the image centrally down the canvas
            }
            //Create a new image from the uploaded picture using the Graphics class

            //Clear the graphic and set the background colour to white

            //Use Antialias and High Quality Bicubic to maintain a good quality picture

            //Save the new bitmap image using 'Png' picture format and the calculated canvas positioning

            Graphics newGraphic = Graphics.FromImage(newBmp);

            try
            {
                newGraphic.Clear(Color.White);

                newGraphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                newGraphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

                newGraphic.DrawImage(upBmp, newX, newY, newWidth, newHeight);

                newBmp.Save(MapPath(filePath), System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                //Show the uploaded resized picture in the image control
                Image1.ImageUrl = filePath;
                Image1.Visible = true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string newError = ex.Message;
                lblError.Text = newError;
            }
            finally
            {
                upBmp.Dispose();
                newBmp.Dispose();
                newGraphic.Dispose();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please select a picture with a file format extension of either Bmp, Jpg, Jpeg, Gif or Png.";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your issue.

Comment: The way you have it set up you would need to call it twice with the 2 sizes you want. You could take the code out of the button click and put it in its own method with width and height params, then call your method with the various sizes you want.

Comment: As @FrebinFrancis says it is not entirely clear what your issue is. Please clarify what problem you are having, what you want the code to do, and what you have tried to do to get there.

Comment: ya.. Can you pass and update answer, i did but its inserting two time. @StephenBrickner

Answer (score 0):

try this
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/upload-multiple-files-using-fileupload-control-in-Asp-Net-4/
it should work for you